# Ember assign id to created record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating a new user with this:

```
var transaction = App.store.transaction();
transaction.createRecord(App.User, {
    firstName: this.get('firstName'),
    lastName: this.get('lastName')
});
transaction.commit();
```

my server is returning

```
{"first_name":"Han","last_name":"Solo","id":"19"}
```

but the newly create User's id is null. Either I'm not returning the right result from the server or there is another step I need to do to assign the new user's id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server should rather return the following json string.

```
{"user":{"first_name":"Han","last_name":"Solo","id":"19"}}
```

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this as I did. More details are in the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/). I did some exploring of my own, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922623/what-is-the-complete-list-of-expected-json-responses-for-ds-restadapter).