# What is the complete list of expected JSON responses for DS.RESTAdapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I am attempting to write a custom express.js based server for an Ember.js app. I am getting along fairly well but I'm constantly getting stuck trying to guess what JSON responses Ember Data is expecting at a given moment.

This brand new documentation is a great start http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/ but not complete enough.

My stabbing in the dark has lead me to understand (Ember pre4, Ember Data 11):

```
Context                                Server URL          Method     Req. Data                  Resp. Data
~~~~~~~                                ~~~~~~~~~~          ~~~~~~     ~~~~~~~~~                  ~~~~~~~~~~
Getting a list of all users            /users              GET                                   {"users":[{...},{...}]}
Getting a particular user              /users/123          GET                                   {"user":{...}}
Creating a user                        /users              POST       {"user":{...}}             ???
Updating a user                        /users/123          PUT        {"user":{...}}             ???
Deleting a user                        /users/123          DELETE     ???                        ???

Creating a user (bulkUpdate)           /users              POST       {"users":[{...},{...}]}    ???
Updating a user (bulkUpdate)           /users/bulk         PUT        {"users":[{...},{...}]}    ???
Deleting a user (bulkUpdate)           /users/123          DELETE     ???                        ???
```

Can someone help me fill in some of these blanks?

**Edit, the complete list of expected JSON responses**

These responses were gleaned from the [ember-data REST adapter unit tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/rest_adapter_test.js) and by watching the network traffic on the [Example Ember Data app](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example).

```
Context                                Server URL          Method     Req. Data                  Resp. Data
~~~~~~~                                ~~~~~~~~~~          ~~~~~~     ~~~~~~~~~                  ~~~~~~~~~~
Getting a list of all users            /users              GET                                   {"users":[{...},{...}]}
Getting a particular user              /users/123          GET                                   {"user":{...}}
Creating a user                        /users              POST       {"user":{...}}             {"user":{...}}
Updating a user                        /users/123          PUT        {"user":{...}}             {"user":{...}}
Deleting a user                        /users/123          DELETE     N/A                        null

Creating a user (bulkCommit)           /users              POST       {"users":[{...},{...}]}    {"users":[{...},{...}]}
Updating a user (bulkCommit)           /users/bulk         PUT        {"users":[{...},{...}]}    {"users":[{...},{...}]}
Deleting a user (bulkCommit)           /users/bulk         DELETE     {"users":[1,2]}            {"users":[1,2]}
```

Comment: So, based on this post and other research. I wrote this gist to convey most of the cases. Please leave feedbacks. Thanks.

https://gist.github.com/ldong/c52f491a88935a8c24337c1326586f99

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of stabbing in the dark, have a look at [rest-adapter-test](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/rest_adapter_test.js)

For example, to fill in your question on response data for bulk updates, [L738](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/rest_adapter_test.js#L736) describes the expected response data:

```
ajaxHash.success({ people: [
  { id: 1, name: "Brohuda Brokatz" },
  { id: 2, name: "Brocarl Brolerche" }
]});
```

Comment: Woah, I sure wish I had seen that sooner. Thank you Michael!

Comment: Updated out-of-date link. If it moves in future, basically just go to ember-data project on github and search project for rest_adapter_test.js - https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/rest_adapter_test.js

Comment: @MikeGrassotti: How is the standard called on which the format of the json requests / replies for ember-data is based? Is there a full specification of the standard somewhere? Does ember-data implement that standard fully?

Comment: this answer is old, file changed its name and example doesn't exit any more. Anyone could please write where to find examples of the response in a https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/rest-adapter-test.js ?

Comment: 2017 Link: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/tests/integration/adapter/rest-adapter-test.js

Answer (score 0):

Currently look for phrases `ajaxResponse(` in `rest-adapter-test.js` source nested in `test("create - a payload with a new ID and data applies the updates"` look alike blocks to read required response of server.