# Ember-data not updating model on PUT request?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, put

With the current ember-data 0.13 is there a way to update a model from the response content of a PUT request?

In my REST api fields (such as updated_at) are set at the server during an object update and the client model needs to be updated with the content of the response from the PUT request.

Specifically, an updated_at property that's used for concurrency handling needs to be set from the PUT response.

Comment: ember-data should update your model based on response to content of a PUT request. Can you post a failing example? Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922623/what-is-the-complete-list-of-expected-json-responses-for-ds-restadapter/14945452#14945452 maybe something there will help

Comment: Thank you Mike, I didn't know it was *supposed* to update, I must be doing something wrong.  Cheers!

Comment: Cool. I looked around and couldn't find a test that verifies this behavior so could be you've uncovered a bug. According to ember-data source it should work: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L225-L227

Comment: Thanks again for your help Mike, just knowing it *should* update was what I needed to know, the rest was breakpoints and tracing to pin it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  For future reference if the REST API returns a payload as a result of a PUT request it must not be inside an array.

I.E. this:

```
{
  "client": {
    "__v": 2,
    "_id": "51d47b5b3f7499341a00006a",        
    "created_at": "2013-07-03T19:28:27.868Z",
    "created_by": "51d47b5b3f7499341a000003",
    "name": "A1",        
    "updated_at": "2013-07-04T21:20:36.311Z",
    "updated_by": "51d47b5b3f7499341a000004",
  }
}
```

And not this:

```
{
  "client": [
    {
      "__v": 2,
      "_id": "51d47b5b3f7499341a00006a",
      "created_at": "2013-07-03T19:28:27.868Z",
      "created_by": "51d47b5b3f7499341a000003",
      "name": "A1",
      "updated_at": "2013-07-04T21:23:11.943Z",
      "updated_by": "51d47b5b3f7499341a000004",
    }
  ]
}
```